Homotopy groups of $\mathbb{R}^4$ with a ring removed
I would like to know what are the homotopy groups of $\mathbb{R}^4$ minus a ring, at least $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$, and $\pi_3$.
It seems clear that $\pi_1 (\mathbb{R}^4 - S^1) = 0$, since the only obstruction to contracting a loop in this space would be the loop that we have excised. Since two loops cannot link in $\mathbb{R}^4$, then it seems the first loop can always be contracted.
What about $\pi_3$? I think a 3-sphere that encloses the ring we have removed would not be contractable, so expect $\pi_3$ to be non-zero... In fact, for this purpose, removing a ring looks equivalent to removing a point, so perhaps:
$\pi_3 (\mathbb{R}^4 - S^1) = \pi_3 (\mathbb{R}^4 - \text{point}) = \pi_3 (S^3) = \mathbb{Z}$ ?
As for $\pi_2$... I really don't know how to go about this.
Disclaimer: I am a physicist with no formal training in algebraic topology, so I am really interested in not only getting the answer to my question but also hearing how a mathematician goes about reasoning for the answer.

If you consider the embedding in $S^4$ instead, Alexander duality tells you that $H_2(S^4 \setminus S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, so since punctures affect at most the top two degrees of homology, you also have $H_2(\mathbb{R}^4 \setminus S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and therefore $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}^4 \setminus S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ (via Hurewicz). I don't see how to go about $\pi_3$, and this might potentially be difficult.

Doesn't this deformation retract to the suspension of what you get in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (so the suspension of $S^2\vee S^1$)? That agrees with what @BenSteffan wrote, and would let you compute $\pi_3$.

@SteveD i.e. $S^3 \vee S^2$? I can't see the deformation retraction, but it's plausible; my geometric intuition is admittedly weak. If it's true, then computing $\pi_3$ should be feasible, although it might still involve some technical effort (it's not generally true that $\pi_k(S^n \vee S^m) \cong \pi_k(S^n) \oplus \pi_k(S^m)$).

@BenSteffan: I definitely could be wrong here. I was just thinking about letting the "ring" be $S^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3\times{0}\subset\mathbb{R}^4$. Then pushing $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^3\times[-1,1]$., then pinching at the $\pm1$ slices. But yeah you're right it would still be hard to get $\pi_3$ (I was thinking of $\pi_3(S^2\vee S^1)$ which is doable).

I think the deformation retraction mentioned by SteveD is true. The way you see it is that  after shrinking to $\Bbb R^3\times[-1,1]$, removing a circle is topologically the same as removing the open cylinder $S^1\times(-1,1)$. Since both caps are contractible subspaces, we get a homotopy equivalence to $S(\Bbb R^3\setminus S^1)$. $\Bbb R^3\setminus S^1$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1$, so we want to compute $\pi_3(S^3\vee S^2)$ and this can be done via cellular approximation since $S^3\vee S^2$ is the $4$-skeleton of $S^3\times S^2$.

@Kevin.S Have you considered making this into an answer?

@BenSteffan I’ll write an answer when I get back home.

I'm expanding my comment above as an answer.
The OP mentions that they come from a physics background with no formal training in algebraic topology, so I will try to keep this answer intuitive and provide links for concepts/theorems.

We have a homotopy equivalence $\Bbb R^4\setminus S^1\simeq S^3\vee S^2$.

Assume $S^1\subseteq\Bbb R^4$ is identified as the unit circle embedded in $\Bbb R^2\times\{0\}^2$ (using the first two dimensions).  We see that $\Bbb R^4\setminus S^1\simeq  (\Bbb R^3\times[-1,1])\setminus S^1$ by shrinking the fourth coordinate. We also have $(\Bbb R^3\times[-1,1])\setminus S^1\simeq (\Bbb R^3\times[-1,1])\setminus(S^1\times(-1,1))$, i.e., homotopy equivalent to the same space but with an open cylinder removed. The latter space can be written as
$$\Bbb R^3\times\{1\}\cup(\Bbb R^3\setminus S^1)\times(-1,1)\cup\Bbb R^3\times\{-1\}$$
Note that $\Bbb R^3\times\{1\}$ and $\Bbb R^3\times\{-1\}$ are both contractible subspaces, so we have a homotopy equivalence
$$(\Bbb R^3\times[-1,1])\setminus(S^1\times(-1,1))\simeq ((\Bbb R^3\times[-1,1])\setminus(S^1\times(-1,1)))/{\sim}$$
where the equivalence relation collapses the "top" $\Bbb R^3\times\{1\}$ to a single point and the "bottom" $\Bbb R^3\times\{-1\}$ to a different point. This is known as the (unreduced) suspension of $\Bbb R^3\setminus S^1$, usually denoted $S(\Bbb R^3\setminus S^1)$.
So, It suffices to figure out the homotopy type of $\Bbb R^3\setminus S^1$. In fact, we have $\Bbb R^3\setminus S^1\simeq S^2\vee S^1$. At this point, I have to resort to geometric arguments as the homotopy equivalence is not easy to describe [We can also use the suspension argument again as pointed out by SteveD in the comment section below]. For a visualization, see example #3 in this link, where the author proves that  a solid sphere (a ball) with a circle in its interior removed is homotopy equivalent to a $2$-sphere with a diameter, which is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1$. Hence $S(S^2\vee S^1)=S^3\vee S^2\simeq \Bbb R^4\setminus S^1$.

$\pi_1(\Bbb R^4\setminus S^1)=0$, $\pi_2(\Bbb R^4\setminus S^1)\cong\Bbb Z$, $\pi_3(\Bbb R^4\setminus S^1)\cong\Bbb Z^2$.

All computations can be transferred to $S^3\vee S^2$ due to the homotopy equivalence. Seifert-Van Kampen theorem tells us $\pi_1(S^3\vee S^2)=0$, so $S^3\vee S^2$ is simply-connected. By Hurewicz theorem, $\pi_2(S^3\vee S^2)\cong H_2(S^3\vee S^2)\cong H_2(S^3)\oplus H_2(S^2)\cong\Bbb Z$. We used homology groups instead as they are generally easier to compute. For the third homotopy group, we need use the fact that the spaces involved in the calculation are CW complexes. Using cellular approximation theorem, one can show that $\pi_3(S^3\vee S^2)\cong \pi_3(S^3\times S^2)$ since $S^3\vee S^2$ is the $4$-skeleton of $S^3\times S^2$, and we know how to compute the latter group. This gives $\pi_3(S^3\vee S^2)\cong\Bbb Z^2$. More generally, for CW complexes $Y, Z$ such that $\dim Y\le n$ for some $n$, cellular approximation implies that $[Y,Z]$ is in bijective correspondence with $[Y,Z^{(n+1)}]$, where $Z^{(n+1)}$ is the $(n+1)$-skeleton of $Z$ and $[Y,Z]$ is the set of homotopy classes of maps from $Y$ to $Z$.

Great answer. Just a note that you can avoid the "geometric arguments" by doing the same suspension trick: $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus S^1$ deformation retracts to $S^1\sqcup{pt}$, and the suspension of that is a sphere with a line connecting the poles, which is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1$.

@SteveD Ah nice! I missed this trick. Thanks for pointing out!
